# Extend Monge's Theorem to ellipse

Tags: geometry

I am trying to generalize Monge's Theorem.

As I search on the internet, many web pages about Monge's Theorem only mention that the theorem applies to the circles, and ellipses seem to have been omitted.

Obviously, Monge's Theorem does not apply to all ellipses. The following image is an example that does not work (the intersections of the tangents are not collinear).

[image]

However, I think that Monge's Theorem applies to the similar ellipses (the ratio of major and minor axes is the same) that are positioned at the same angle (the ellipses cannot be rotated). The following image is an example that does work.

Could people help me justify the result?
[image]

Comment: Can't you find an affine transformation to turn your ellipse set-up into one with circles?

Comment: 1. Use circles. 2. Scale the width of the whole diagram until the circles become the ellipses that you want. 3. Done.

Comment: That's right, I didn't think of that. Thank you for the hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest formulation and proof are probably through plane projective geometry: Given three general conics that have the same intersection with the line at infinity, you should be able to show that

- they are pairwise homothetic using the [five points rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic) and
- the centers of homothety are collinear *à la* [Desargues](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/MongeDesargues.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

From a projective point of view all circles has two common points, the circle points in infinity. So the genralization og Monges theorem is that when three conics has two common points, then the three pairs of tangents will meet on the same line. A special case of this is when ellipses are similar, then they have two commen points on the line in infinity.